# Call function from one component from a component Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm a beginner in Angular. I've been facing this issue with calling a method in a component from a component, which they are not related to. I followed a lot of tutorials on the internet but haven't found the solution.

So the detail is:
There are 2 unrelated components. The first component has a button and if I click that button, the string from the first component should be sent to a function in the second component and in that function It should display the string into the console. But the problem I'm facing here is that the function is called only once before I click and it just displays the value "111" which is the default value. Please help me

First component:

```js
export class FirstComponent implements OnInit{
  constructor(location:Location, private renderer : Renderer2, private element : ElementRef, private router: Router, private httpClient: HttpClient, private servic: MainService) {
  }
  clickMe() {
     this.servic.sendMessage("001");
  }
}
```

Second component:

```js
export class SecondComponent implements OnInit {
  clickEventSubs:Subscription;
  constructor(public servic: MainService, private spinner: NgxSpinnerService, private router: Router){} 
    this.clickEventSubs = this.servic.receiveMessage().subscribe(message => {
      this.toggle(message);
    })
  public toggle(state: string){
    console.log(state);
  }
}
```

Shared service:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MainService {
  private message = new BehaviorSubject<string>("111");
  sendMessage(mess:string) {
    this.message.next(mess);
  }
  receiveMessage(): Observable<any> {
    return this.message.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Comment: *But the problem I'm facing is the function is called only once before I click and it just displays the value "111" which is the default value* . This is the expected behaviour of your code. What exactly do you want?

Comment: Do you see the click me function? It should send 001 to the second component

Answer (score 0):

When relationships between component is **Child > Parent** -
**Share date via @viewChild()**

In First Component, Use @ViewChild() and pass second component name as an
argument -

```
@ViewChild(SecondComponent) secondChildView!: SecondComponent;
```

Then call the second component's function in the first component's function -

```
 import {ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

 export class FirstComponent implements OnInit{
 @ViewChild(SecondComponent) secondChildView!: SecondComponent;

 constructor() {}
 
   clickMe() {
     this.secondChildView.toggle('001'); 
  }
}
```

Whenever you call clickMe function it will call the toggle function of second component and you will get the value in toggle function from the first component.

```
export class SecondComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor(){} 

 public toggle(state: string){
  console.log(state);
 }
}
```

Comment: I tried this way but i didn't work since those aren't parent-child components

Comment: Ok, Then your way is correct what you were doing.
I have tried your code, I am not having any problem with it. Please share your html code also and tell me what error are you getting and first check clickMe function, is always working or not.